# Symfony 4 error: Unused binding "$projectDir" in service

Tags: php, symfony

While updating from Symfony 3.4 to 4.1, when I php bin/console, I got the following error.
I want to take parameters in a url reference way.
What is the cause?
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service

Error code

```
Unused binding "$projectDir" in service "common.parameterService".
```

config/services.yaml

```yaml
parameters:
    parameter_name: XXX

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: false
        autoconfigure: false
        public: false
        bind:
            $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'

    common.parameterService:
        class:  AppBundle\Model\Service\ParameterService
        arguments:  [ "@service_container" ]
```

AppBundle/Model/Service/ParameterService.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use AppBundle\Model\Service\BaseService;

/**
 * 
 */
class ParameterService extends BaseService
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param string 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getParameter()
    {
        return $this->params->get('parameter_name');
    }
```

Comment: An autowire feature with `autowire: false`?

Comment: @scottie320 - Is this an attempt to replace your existing legacy Parameters class?  If so then I fear you are going down the wrong path.  In the classes that currently contain Parameters::getParameter calls, you will want to inject whatever parameters or services they need.

Comment: @SubCore That's right. From the old Symfony I'm updating, so I don't think I need the autowire function.

Comment: @Cerad You're right.
Does that mean you can get it by setting parameters in Parameters :: getParameter?

Comment: Please, don't inject service_container :). With Autowiring, all dependencies will be automatically injected

Comment: @scottie320 You are still not 'getting' the concepts of services and dependency injection.  Your Parameters class can still work once you have initialized it properly so you might want to set it aside while you work on updating the rest of your legacy app.  I would suggest creating a fresh 4.4 project and then follow the docs and create a few sample services and do some injection etc.  And then try to apply what you learned to selected portions of you app.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you don't have enough rep for a chat.  Might consider posting on the Reddit Symfony site.

Comment: @Cerad Certainly I don't understand yet, so I'd like to give it a try.
Also, I went back to 3.4 and started modifying the service in the form of autowire.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you. I will also consider posting on Reddit.

Answer (score -1):

It means you have declared this:

```
    bind:
        $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

but have not injected the `$projectDir` in the `ParameterService` nor in any other services in that file.

You can delete these two lines:

```
    bind:
        $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Certainly, if you delete bind, the error disappears. However, what I want to achieve is getting the parameters. Is it all right to set $ projectDir to Service? I tried it, but it doesn't work.